# I'm stuck with a simple MIDI program

Tags: midi, coremidi

My goal is to write a simple (console) program like this:

1. get MIDI message from MIDI Input
2. modifiy message (or add messages)
3. write message to MIDI output

Since I am completely new to C++ and it's been 15 years since I last wrote some C code, I searched a while and came across RtMidi (http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) which I thought could help me to reach my goal.

I am using Xcode to do the compiling and stuff.

I also figured it makes sense to use a callback function.

The code from RtMidi works right out of the box.
I can open virtual MIDIports, and I get my MIDI messages into the callback function where it is output to the console.

But now I am stuck since I haven't understood the working of the callback implementation (I think).

My questions are:

- Do I have to do the modifications of the MIDI message within the callback function?
- If yes, how can I write to the MIDI out from the callback function?
- If no: how do I get the MIDI message into my cpp-code (probably by passing a pointer to a userdata field)?
- But then - how is my main code triggered to process the message when it arrives in the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - has been solved.

I definitely was lack of understanding C++ .... I specified a pointer instead of a variable.

Matt